# How to initialize PrintWriter array?

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

I have to create n number of files. N is random but it will be in this range 1<=n<=7. When I run this program it gives NullPointException. file_num is number of files to be created. If I remove null from the first line it tells me to initialize the array.

```
PrintWriter[] writer=null;
for(int j=0;j<file_num;j++)
{
    System.out.println("J is "+j);
    writer[j] =new PrintWriter(new File("file"+(j+1)+".csv"));
}
```

Comment: _it gives NullPointException..._  because `writer=null` ?

Comment: but if I remove that, it won't even compile and ask me to initialize the array

Comment: _ask me to initialize the array..._ Of course it does. Read over java arrays again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run this program it gives NullPointException.

That's because

```
 PrintWriter[] writer = null;
```

You should initialize `writer` array with new empty array of size `file_num`

```
PrintWriter[] writer = new PrintWriter[file_num];
```